# How to integrate into Qt an external audio library for Android? JUCE? Superpowered?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, juce

Has anyone managed to successfully integrate Qt with another audio library or SDK?

I am developing a Android (armeabi-v7a) application using Qt 5.13.2 on my macOs 10.13.6.

Being the limitation of Qt as regards DSP, I was considering using the functionalities of external library. However this has been a real pain, probably because I am a beginner when it comes to low-level software engineering.

The example in this rep(https://github.com/nikeocom/qt_with_juce_example) does build and deploy for my android but it then crashes giving the errors reported below. 
Same thing happens when I try to integrate Superpowered SDK: it does compile, but than it crashes giving errors about an invalid pointer.

ERRORS:

```
E/AEE/AED (21028): timed out waiting for tid=20709 to stop
W/libbacktrace(21028): virtual bool BacktracePtrace::ReadWord(uintptr_t, word_t*): invalid pointer 0xbec2b000 reading from tid 20709, ptrace() strerror(errno)=No such process
W/libbacktrace(21028): virtual bool BacktracePtrace::ReadWord(uintptr_t, word_t*): invalid pointer 0xbec2b040 reading from tid 20709, ptrace() strerror(errno)=No such process
W/libbacktrace(21028): virtual bool BacktracePtrace::ReadWord(uintptr_t, word_t*): invalid pointer 0xbec2b050 reading from tid 20709, ptrace() strerror(errno)=No such process
W/libbacktrace(21028): virtual bool BacktracePtrace::ReadWord(uintptr_t, word_t*): invalid pointer 0xbec2b070 reading from tid 20709, ptrace() strerror(errno)=No such process
etc...
```

I would really appreciate any help and suggestions on which audio external libraries work on Qt.